# Alamofire Request initially returns value but is received as nil when passed through completion handler

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, alamofire

I'm using Alamofire to make a simple GET request as so:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, url, headers: User.sharedInstance.httpHeader())
        .responseJSON { request,response,result in
            print(result.value)
            completionHandler(responseObject: result.value as? NSDictionary, error: result.error as? NSError)
        }
```

This line `print(result.value)` prints the expected JSON result:

```
▿ Optional((
        {
        id = 1;
        name = "Texas Dropshop";
    },
        {
        id = 2;
        name = "Closepin Landromat";
    }
))
  ▿ Some : 2 elements
    ▿ [0] : 2 elements
      ▿ [0] : 2 elements
        - .0 : id
      ▿ [1] : 2 elements
        - .0 : name
        - .1 : Texas Dropshop
    ▿ [1] : 2 elements
      ▿ [0] : 2 elements
        - .0 : id { ... }
      ▿ [1] : 2 elements
        - .0 : name { ... }
        - .1 : Closepin Landromat
```

But when it is received in the completion handler's method:

```
 GetDefaultUserDropshop.execute (){ (responseObject, error) -> () in
            print("responseObject = \(responseObject); error = \(error)")
        }
```

the value of the responseObject is nil. I'm assuming this has to do with the casting:

```
responseObject: result.value as? NSDictionary
```

but am kind of lost on how to solve it as i'm transitioning to swift.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your response is an Array, not a Dictionary

Answer (score 0):

The response was an Array, not a Dictionary